# Convert data from columns to rows without losing already stored data below?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

How do I convert values from a column into rows without losing data in existing rows below? For example, I have data in this format:

```
      A   |    B    | C      |
1 | Apples| Berries | Cakes  |
2 | Pies  | Crusts  | Nuts   |
```

I need the following:

```
     A.  
1| Apples  
2| Berries  
3| Cakes  

1| Pies  
2| Crusts  
3| Nuts
```

Comment: I should say I need Column A Row 1 Apples Row 2 Berries Row 3 Cakes Row 4 Pies Row 5 Crusts Row 6 Nuts...

Comment: You can [edit] your question to update it as you like, rather than comment on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have space available to the right or below your data, select and copy the row data. Then select a cell in the available space and "right" click to get the context menu. Choose `Transpose` from the paste options.

[image]

Once you've converted it, delete the empty rows where the data was before.

Comment: Thanks CharlieRB. I do not have space available below the data, I have a sheet with over 500 lines and all lines have to be converted to the new format. When I try to use transpose, it replaces existing data. Any other suggestions? Also I do not have readily available space to the right, the columns go all the way to BG.

Comment: Paste transpose the data to a new sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Divide numbers in separate column & write description above to have a lable (say - Number). Afterwards select all data (all rows 7 columns); use Insert Pivot table (as data source all table will be used) & chose where you want to have it. Table Field List will appear & in row lables include Number; A; B; C (these are lables of your shown columns above). In there (in field settings to each of this row lable (each - A, B, C) choose in Subtotals$Filters tab - none; in layout & print tab - Show item labels in outline form - tick here Display in the same column. Afterwards paste special as numbers to format what you need/don't need - filter our only text etc. and you will receive data in columns. later use automatic numbering in column before (insert it). maybe that helps.